# Dynamically loading hi-res images into UIScrollView

Tags: iphone, uikit, ipad, uiscrollview

I've been looking into creating a gallery mode in my application. 
The functionality will be identical to the built in Photos App.

Here's the flow:
1. You touch on a thumbnail and ...
2. a modal view displays a large detail version of the image
3. You have the ability to scroll horizontally through all the images in the gallery **while in this modal view**

I'm stuck on step 3.

How do I dynamically load hi res images into a scroll view? I understand I need to set the contentSize for the the scrollView but how do I do that when I've only selected and loaded one image? What delegate methods do I need to implement and what does the heavy lifting look like?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Refer to the following example project from apple, it shows how to use a scroll view to scroll horizontally through some views, u shouod only need to change the conents of those views to contain ur images http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/iPad/index.html#samplecode/PageControl/Introduction/Intro.html

Comment: thanks for the link. Even that sample code doesn't have what I'm looking for. Looking at the source I see this comment:

// A possible optimization would be to unload the views+controllers which are no longer visible

Which is exactly what I'm looking to do.

Comment: That shouldn't be that tough, u have the index of the curnt pages so ud want to unload the pages that are 2 or more index away from the page..